# error[E0308]: mismatched types , Default generic type is invalid

Tags: generics, rust, struct, types, default

I've tried specifying the type in two different places, but the compiler still throws an error.

```
use serde::Serialize;

// 1: try to set default type.
struct Student<T = Option<String>> {
    age: i32,
    data: T
}

impl<T> Student<T> where T: Serialize {
    
    fn new(age: i32) -> Self {
        Student {
            age, 
            data: <Option<String>>::None // 2. try to set default type
        }
    }
    
    
    // fn new_with_data(age: i32, data: T) -> Self {
    //     Student {
    //         age,
    //         data
    //     }
    // }
}


fn main() {
 
    let stu1 = Student::new(123);
    
    //let stu2 = Student::new_with_data(123, <Option<()>>::None);
    
}
```

got error:

```
   Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:13:19
   |
8  | impl<T> Student<T> where T: Serialize {
   |      - this type parameter
...
13 |             data: <Option<String>>::None
   |                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected type parameter `T`, found enum `std::option::Option`
   |
   = note: expected type parameter `T`
                        found enum `std::option::Option<std::string::String>`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0308`.
error: could not compile `playground` due to previous error
```

the play link: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=749e31fae6091226b99e233a016ca0c8

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is while you set a default type, the `impl` block does not require that `T` is the default. `<Option<String>>::None` is only a valid value if the type is `Option<String>`, but this does not require that to be the case.

```rust
/// `T` is unconstrained and may or may not be `Option<T>`
impl<T> Student<T> {}

/// This implements student for only one specific generic type (`Option<String>`). This
/// functionality will not be available for other generic types.
impl Student<Option<String>> {}

/// Here we don't include the generic so it implements for only the default generic. This is
/// equivalent to the previous version, but the generic is assumed to be the default value. 
impl Student {}
```

What I suspect you want to do is make the data generic. Instead of making the the `Option` generic, we just make the data it holds generic. We can still set a default value without running into this issue.

```rust
struct Student<T = String> {
    age: i32,
    /// Some optional generic data
    data: Option<T>
}

impl<T> Student<T> where T: Serialize {
    fn new(age: i32) -> Self {
        Student {
            age, 
            data: None,
        }
    }
    
    
    fn new_with_data(age: i32, data: T) -> Self {
        Student {
            age,
            data: Some(data),
        }
    }
}
```

Another option would be to keep the type the same, but split the `impl` to two parts. This way we can require the use of `new_with_data` if the data is not an `Option`, but still allow the usage of `new` in some cases.

```rust
struct Student<T = Option<String>> {
    age: i32,
    data: T
}

impl<T> Student<Option<T>> where T: Serialize {
    fn new(age: i32) -> Self {
        Student {
            age, 
            data: None,
        }
    }
}

impl<T> Student<T> where T: Serialize {
    fn new_with_data(age: i32, data: T) -> Self {
        Student { age, data }
    }
}
```

Comment: I feel almost perfect, thanks for your answer!
if I want to new Student, I have to write: Student::<Option<String>>::new();
is there any way to implement: Student::new();

Comment: You have a couple of options. The easiest is to just implement more of your program. If the compiler sees that `data` is being passed to a function or used by something that only allows type `Option<String>`, it can infer that you want a `Student<Option<String>>`. However this is not always the case. One other option would be to make a type alias for `Student<Option<String>>` so you do not need to write the full name every time (Ex: `type CollegeStudent = Student<Option<String>>;` then use `CollegeStudent::new()`).

Answer (score 0):

According to your method, I made a little modification and realized what I wanted.

```
use serde::Serialize;

struct Student<T = Option<String>> {
    age: i32,
    /// Some optional generic data
    data: T
}

impl Student<Option<String>> {
    fn new(age: i32) -> Self {
        Student {
            age, 
            data: None,
        }
    }
}

impl<T> Student<T> where T: Serialize {
    
    fn new_with_data(age: i32, data: T) -> Self {
        Student {
            age, data
        }
        
    }
}

fn main() {
 
    let stu1 = Student::new(123);
    let stu2 = Student::new_with_data(123, 2222);
    
}
```